# Intersection of line and curve depending on parameter

Tags: polynomials

> Find the range of values of $p$ for which the line $ y=-4-px$ does not intersect the curve $y=x^{2}+2x+2p$

I think I probably have to find the discriminant of the curve but I don't get how that would help.

Comment: Take  a  look  at  this  for  better  posting :  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Equate the two expressions for $y$ and then re-arrange to form a quadratic equation

For the equation to have no real root, the discrimant $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ must hold. From here, you can find the range of values for $p$ for which the line does not meet the curve.

Answer (score 0):

The two equations give $x^2+(2+p)x+2p+4=0$, so you have to calculate the discriminant of this. You get : $-7p^2-4p-12$ which is always negative.

Answer (score 0):

Equating slope to the required line slope for finding tangency point which demarcates between intersection and non-intersection.

$ 2 x + 2 = - p$

or

$ x = -(1 + p/2) $

and

$ y = p\, ( p/2 +1) -4 $

EDIT 1:

The parabola

$ y = 2 x ( x+1) -4 $

is envelope to the set of tangents

$ y = -p x - 4, -\infty < p <  \infty  $

Clairaut's form differential equations with solution  $ y = a \,p\, x + p^2. $